# Turn a list of strings into a list of lists of strings based on string

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list of strings that looks as follows:

`example = ['1','4','6','7','9','...','11','14','18','...','21']`

Now, I want to turn `example` into a list of lists of strings based on the divisor string `'...'`

My desired output is:

`output = [['1','4','6','7','9'],['11','14','18'],['21']]`

I used the following code, but this seems cumbersome:

```
output = []
temp_list = []
for sign in example:
    if sign == '...':
        output.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = []
    else:
        temp_list.append(sign)
output.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

example = ["1", "4", "6", "7", "9", "...", "11", "14", "18", "...", "21"]

out = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(example, lambda v: v != "...") if k]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['1', '4', '6', '7', '9'], ['11', '14', '18'], ['21']]
```